Postgres container on Windows 11 (WSL) crashes periodically
We have a several containers that comprise our app. One of the containers is a Python process that reads some data from a database container (Postgres) and writes data back to it.
I have had this setup for a while and it has worked well on Ubuntu. We replicated this on Windows and using the WSL backend for docker and we see the Postgres container crash intermittently. I have looked at the container logs and the only statement indicative of failure or unusual are like so:
FATAL:  terminating background worker "parallel worker" due to administrator command FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
I concluded that this might be due to increased number of connections or excessive memory consumption. So, I added pgBouncer in front of it. But the crashes are still persistent.
I am using a AMD Ryzen 7 5700G with Radeon Graphics            3.80 GHz with 64GB RAM. I also do not have a wslconfig file setup, so this means that WSL should be able to expand as much as needed and the same applies per container. I am using Docker Desktop 4.32 and the latest Windows 11 build (22631.4460).
Any suggestions about how I should debug this further are appreciated.

Find the pertinent messages in the PostgreSQL log file. The one you show might be a follow-up message of a crash, or it could be unrelated.


I see unknown intermittent crashes and Windows and I immediately go to Anti-Virus software.  2) WSL is notable for it's lack of stability. If you want LInux use Linux without the Windows overhead.

